# How to change where flash caches video files?

Tags: windows-7, flash, flash-player

When I watch videos on youtube or similar sites, flash saves the buffered video information to the disk. Unfortunately it saves it to drive c, which is very inconvenient for me. Is there any way for me to define where the buffered data is saved - particularly, so I could move it to a different drive?

I've tried searching for this option in the Flash Player settings manager ([global storage panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html) and [website storage panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html)) but could not find anything relevant.